# Singleton? Or is there a better way?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm about to build a singleton but I'm not sure if it's the right solution.

I have this problem I have a class that creates a URLSessionTaskDelegate. I would like to use that delegate in another class to get some information from the file upload.

So I was thinking If I could put this plus some other information in to an object like this:

```
    public class UploadQueueCellData
    {
        let _FileName:String
        let _UploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate
        let _ImageData:Data
        init(fileName:String,imageData:Data,uploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate)
        {
            _FileName = fileName
            _ImageData = imageData
            _UploadTaskDelegate = uploadTaskDelegate
        }

.... etc
}
```

And then store it in a singleton with a array inside it:

```
        public class ImageUploadQueue
    {
        private var _queue = [UploadQueueCellData]()
        private let imageUploadQueue:ImageUploadQueue? = nil
        public func GetImageUploadQueueInstance() -> ImageUploadQueue
        {
            if imageUploadQueue == nil
            {
                imageUploadQueue = ImageUploadQueue()
                return imageUploadQueue
            }
            else
            {
                return imageUploadQueue!
            }
        }
        private init()
        {

        }
    .... etc
}
```

and then just use that to update information as change happens in another class.

But is there a better way without a singleton ? and am I even doing the singleton correct from a Swift 3 point of view ?

**Edit:**

so I I see that I'm doing the singleton wrong:

```
    public class ImageUploadQueue
{
    private var _queue = [UploadQueueCellData]()
    //private let imageUploadQueue:ImageUploadQueue? = nil
    static let shared = ImageUploadQueue()

    private init()
    {

    }
```

Would that be better then? But the question remains is there not a better approach than using the singleton pattern for this? I say better simply because I regard the singleton pattern as a last resort.

Comment: And where is singleton ?, I couldn't find singletone anywhere in code

Comment: @MikeAlter `GetImageUploadQueueInstance()` returns the "singleton" (tied to each ImageUploadQueue... OK not really the singleton pattern.)

Comment: @MikeAlter well I might be using a wrong way of making it. the ImageUploadQueue is the class I intended to be a singleton but I'm usually a .net developer

Comment: Well, in the case that you are just instantiating ImageUploadQueue you might want to store it on a property of the class somewhere ...

Comment: I thought that private let imageUploadQueue:ImageUploadQueue? = nil was a property oh I see what you mean

Comment: Singletone object syntax   `static let shared = ImageUploadQueue()` use `shared` for all operation of  `ImageUploadQueue` class

Comment: @MikeAlter I have  changed according to your syntax ?

Comment: Yes, Now it is correct

Comment: @MikeAlter thanks for informing me of my error :) would had made quite a problem later on I imagine

Comment: By seeing your code , you should go through this tutorial for better understanding of  concurrent  operations and queue  https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

Comment: @MikeAlter will do that then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem arose from the fact that I couldn't get a class I created in one view to display information in another view. my solution to this was the singleton solution above it worked but I felt dirty for using that solution.

I finally found a different way to do this. instead of the singleton I've just created a class containing the Array just like the singleton did above like this:

```
public class ImageUploadQueue
{
   private var _queue = [UploadQueueCellData]()
   ....//Class specific code
}
```

and then just use that class as a reference to the Data just like the singleton with the exception that my class above it
had this function that enabled the view to use the information in the queue

```
public func GetUploadQueue()->ImageUploadQueue
{
       return _networkRequester.uploadQueue
}
```

However that class is created by viewA and I needed the information in ViewB.
so I did this in viewB

```
var uploader:ImageUpload
{
     get
     {
         return ((self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as! ViewController).uploader
     }
     set
     {
           (self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController).uploader = newValue
     }
}
```

And it solved my initial problem with not being able to get information from viewA to ViewB at the same time avoided the use of a singleton.